# Time complexity: O(log n) versus O(log 2n)

Tags: time-complexity, language-agnostic, big-o, logarithm

Is O(log n) the same as O(log 2n)?

Comment: log(2n) = log(2) + log(n) = log(n) + constant

Comment: Yes, only n is important, multiplicative factors can be ignored. In the case of log it is even "more negligible", indeed log(2n) = log(n) + log(2), so the log 2 term will be negligible as soon as n is "big"

Answer (score 2):

By [laws of logarithms](https://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mc-bus-loglaws-2009-1.pdf), `log(2N) = log(2) + log(N)` and since you are writing it in big O, what you get is `O(log(2)) + O(log(N)) = O(log(N)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, O(log n) and O(log 2n) mean the same thing. This is because

> log 2n = log 2 + log n,

and since log 2 is a constant, it's ignored by big-O notation.

Going a bit broader than this, properties of logarithms mean that logs of many common expressions end up being equivalent to O(log n). For example, log n<sup>k</sup>, for any fixed constant k, is O(log n) because

> log n<sup>k</sup> = k log n = O(log n).